# Парсер для файла коллекции Postman на GO

Tags: golang, postman

Планирую написать парсер на Go+goQuery с веб версии приложения Postman. Хочу результатом парса выводить ссылки на отдельные файлы в коллекции, может кто подсказать как именно искать в веб-приложениях, нужные вкладки, когда в DevTools нету ссылок а только div и прочее. Ориентироваться на div+название? или это всё дело вообще на desktope приложении лучше искать

Comment: а что такое postman у Вас? и что там за коллекции? но в любом случае можно начать с изучения языка.

Comment: тогда подождем того, кто знает, что такое "вебверсия постмана".